# Checkstyle Plugin does not add gradle tasks

Tags: android, gradle, checkstyle, gradle-plugin

i want to use checkstyle plugin in my gradle project, the gradle documentation says that it will add a few tasks:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html

```
checkstyleMain, checkstyleTest, checkstyleSourceSet
```

I added this into my app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
```

I want to run gradle task from cmd to perform code style check, but there are no one checkstyle task. I checked the whole list by typing:

```
./gradlew tasks
```

I also tried to add checkstyle jar as library dependency to app module.
Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong and how can i get my checkstyle tasks?

Answer (score 8):

Well, the checkstyle plugin adds its tasks in the *Other tasks* virtual task group. Those are really the tasks which have *not* been assigned to a task group. So, they are shown only when you run `./gradlew tasks --all` (note the `--all`).

Complete working *build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'java';
apply plugin: 'checkstyle';
```

Then run `./gradlew tasks --all`, output:

```
<...snip...>
Other tasks
-----------
checkstyleMain - Run Checkstyle analysis for main classes
checkstyleTest - Run Checkstyle analysis for test classes
<...snip...>
```

If you want the Checkstyle tasks to appear without `--all`, then assign them to a task group, for example:

```
tasks.withType(Checkstyle).each {
    it.group = 'verification'
}
```

Comment: Thomas, I should have clarified a few things: 1. I'm using android plugin `com.android.[library | application]` 2. I did use the --all flag. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at other Android projects, built with Gradle, that run checkstyle (thanks Square) I found that I needed to do some setup for the task to appear. Without the task declaration I would still see my initial error.

build.gradle:

```
...
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

...

checkstyle {
    configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
    ignoreFailures false
    showViolations true
    toolVersion = "7.8.1"
}

task Checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
    source 'src/main/java'
    ignoreFailures false
    showViolations true
    include '**/*.java'
    classpath = files()
}

// adds checkstyle task to existing check task
afterEvaluate {
    if (project.tasks.getByName("check")) {
        check.dependsOn('checkstyle')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need a checkstyle configuration file, either by placing one at the [default location](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension:config) as documented or by configuring it explicitly.

For example:

```
checkstyle {
  config = resources.text.fromFile('config/checkstyle.xml')
}
```

Comment: You need a configuration file for the whole thing to be meaningful, but you don't need it to just make the tasks appear.