# How to add checkstyle to a libGDX project?

Tags: gradle, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

I've the following `libGDX` project: [https://github.com/Glusk2/sprouts](https://github.com/Glusk2/sprouts/tree/d891b6296def75cd363bb081f2046f69df4ebd34)

I've tried adding `checkstyle` to the entire project in the root `build.gradle` file, like so:

```
// ...
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"
    apply plugin: "checkstyle"
    // ...
}
// ...
```

and added `config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml` to the root project.

---

But it doesn't work. I get this error after running `./gradlew build connectedCheck`:

```
:android:compileJava                 
<path-to-project>\sprouts\android\src\com\github\glusk2\sprouts\AndroidLauncher.java:3: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Bundle;            
                    ^
<path-to-project>\sprouts\android\src\com\github\glusk2\sprouts\AndroidLauncher.java:9: error: cannot access Activity
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
        ^
    class file for android.app.Activity not found
<path-to-project>\sprouts\android\src\com\github\glusk2\sprouts\AndroidLauncher.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                    ^
    symbol:   class Bundle
    location: class AndroidLauncher
<path-to-project>\sprouts\android\src\com\github\glusk2\sprouts\AndroidLauncher.java:10: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
<path-to-project>\sprouts\android\src\com\github\glusk2\sprouts\AndroidLauncher.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                ^
    symbol:   variable super
    location: class AndroidLauncher
<path-to-project>\sprouts\android\src\com\github\glusk2\sprouts\AndroidLauncher.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
                initialize(new Sprouts(), config);
                ^
    symbol:   method initialize(Sprouts,AndroidApplicationConfiguration)
    location: class AndroidLauncher
6 errors
:android:compileJava FAILED
```

Comment: I don't know gradle but these seem to be compile errors unrelated to checkstyle or it's files.

Comment: I don't mind, I would rather see you get your issue sorted then what tags are listed. Can you confirm it isn't a checkstyle problem by removing checkstyle from the project and see if gradle build still fails without it? Maybe work backwards to the smallest denominator that causes the failure if the project builds successfully without any changes.

Comment: Was this resolved? Githhub project merged in checkstyle and fixed a bunch of the code. See https://github.com/Glusk2/sprouts/pull/23/files .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the `checkstyle` plugin to an Android gradle project does nothing (it adds no checkstyle tasks) by default because:

> Note that the Android plugin uses its own implementation of source sets.

[Android Gradle plugin; sourceSets{}](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension:sourceSets(org.gradle.api.Action))

> The Android plugin has its own `sourceSet` concept and does not populate the `sourceSet` collection of the `java-base` plugin. 
> So applying a plugin like `checkstyle` will do **nothing** by default.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36972352#comment21

---

But in my case, the task list containing the string "checkstyle" looked like this:

```sh
$ ./gradlew tasks --all | grep checkstyle
android:checkstyleMain - Run Checkstyle analysis for main classes //<-- this should not be here :)
core:checkstyleMain - Run Checkstyle analysis for main classes
desktop:checkstyleMain - Run Checkstyle analysis for main classes
html:checkstyleMain - Run Checkstyle analysis for main classes
ios:checkstyleMain - Run Checkstyle analysis for main classes
core:checkstyleTest - Run Checkstyle analysis for test classes
desktop:checkstyleTest - Run Checkstyle analysis for test classes
html:checkstyleTest - Run Checkstyle analysis for test classes
ios:checkstyleTest - Run Checkstyle analysis for test classes
```

How come that task `android:checkstyleMain` was added to the list?

It turns out this was the reason (android project `build.gradle` file):

```
// ...
eclipse {
    // ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
```

It set the `sourceSets` that the `checkstyle` plugin could detect, but configuration was obviously incomplete because the build failed for task: `android:checkstyleMain`.
The above `eclipse` block among others added configuration for the [Eclipse ADT](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt) plugin, which has been unsupported for a while now so I've decided to remove that block altogether.

```sh
$ ./gradlew tasks --all | grep checkstyle
core:checkstyleMain - Run Checkstyle analysis for main classes
desktop:checkstyleMain - Run Checkstyle analysis for main classes
html:checkstyleMain - Run Checkstyle analysis for main classes
ios:checkstyleMain - Run Checkstyle analysis for main classes
core:checkstyleTest - Run Checkstyle analysis for test classes
desktop:checkstyleTest - Run Checkstyle analysis for test classes
html:checkstyleTest - Run Checkstyle analysis for test classes
ios:checkstyleTest - Run Checkstyle analysis for test classes
```

Success! But I still haven't managed to get checkstyle working with the android project.

---

After reading many similar questions about checkstyle tasks not showing for android projects...

- [Get Android gradle plugin & checkstyle working together / command line usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17050654/6367213)
- [Checkstyle Plugin does not add gradle tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47479046/6367213)

... I've come up with the solution.

---

### Solution

Root `build.gradle`:

```
// ...
allprojects {
     apply plugin: "eclipse"
     apply plugin: "idea"
+    apply plugin: "checkstyle"

+    checkstyle {
+        configFile file("${project.rootDir}/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
+    }
// ...
}
// ...
```

Android `build.gradle`:

```
+task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
+    source 'src'
+    include '**/*.java'
+    exclude '**/gen/**'
+    exclude '**/R.java'
+    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
+    classpath = files()
+}
+check.dependsOn "checkstyle"

// ...

-// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
-eclipse {
-    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse -plugin
-    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
-    sourceSets {
-        main {
-            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
-        }
-    }
-
-    jdt {
-        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
-        targetCompatibility = 1.6
-    }
-
-    classpath {
-        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
-        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
-    }
-
-    project {
-        name = appName + "-android"
-        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
-        buildCommands.clear();
-        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
-        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
-        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
-        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
-    }
-}
```